# Delay using Verilog for PR controller

Tags: verilog

i want to shift a signal by fixed number of clock cycles. I receive the signal from adc. kindly let me know how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

**HINT: Not a full answer**

A 8 bit flip-flop in verilog might look like:

```
reg [7:0] a;

always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    // Active Low Reset condition
    a <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    a <= input_eight_bit;
  end
end
```

To delay for multiple clock cycles you need multiple flip-flops feeding from one to the next. This creates a pipe line or delay line.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. i have tried using a shift register,

Comment: but i am not getting desired output.. can u pls tel me wat is the problem with the code? shiftreg <={shiftreg[delay-2:0],adc_data_ch1};
     adc_data_chd <=shiftreg[delay-1];

Comment: How wide is the data your wanting to delay? 1 bit or multi bit? Can you add definition of `shiftreg`?